# wordpress same permalink on different pages

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, multisite

I'm working in a multisite in wordpress. I need to add in the Home page tag on the menu, a submenu redirecting to the home page of the site where I am and another to the home page to the other site of the multisite.

THE ISSUE: I can not put a permalink that is in use already. Does anyone have an idea about how to put the same permalink in different pages?

Thank you all

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"I can not put a permalink that is in use already"_? Wordpress has no such restriction.

Comment: ahaaaa I was looking deeply to give you a better explanation and the solution came by itself!

I didn't know I can add custom permalinks in the menu!!! :o that's great!

Thank you anyway!

Comment: that's great, I'm glad you managed to fix the problem :)